# @datadog/browser-rum compilation issue on 'allowedTracingOrigins' property

Tags: angular, typescript, datadog

I am struggling with a typings issue on the library @datadog/browser-rum:

```
Error: node_modules/@datadog/browser-rum-core/src/domain/configuration.ts:100:3 
error TS2322: Type '{ applicationId: string; version: string; actionNameAttribute: string; premiumSampleRate: number; allowedTracingOrigins: readonly (string | RegExp)[]; tracingSampleRate: number; excludedActivityUrls: readonly (string | RegExp)[]; trackInteractions: boolean; trackFrustrations: boolean; trackViewsManually: boolean; de...' is not assignable to type 'RumConfiguration'.

Types of property 'allowedTracingOrigins' are incompatible.
The type 'readonly (string | RegExp)[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type '(string | RegExp)[]'.
```

On the implementation, no typescript errors are raised, it only comes from the library.

The dependencies:

```
Angular@12
typescript@4.3.5
@datadog/browser-rum@4.17.2
node@12.20.2
```

The implementation:

```js
import {
    APP_INITIALIZER,
    FactoryProvider,
} from '@angular/core';
import { Environment } from '@shared/base/class/environment.class';
import { RumEvent } from '@datadog/browser-rum-core/src/rumEvent.types';
import { RumEventDomainContext } from '@datadog/browser-rum-core/src/domainContext.types';
import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';

function factory(...dependencies: [Environment]) {
    return () => init(...dependencies);
}

function init(environment: Environment): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (!environment.dataDog) {
            return resolve();
        }
        datadogRum.init({
            applicationId: environment?.dataDog?.applicationId,
            clientToken: environment?.dataDog?.clientToken,
            site: environment?.dataDog?.site,
            service: environment?.dataDog?.service,
            env: environment.env,
            version: environment.appVersion,
            sampleRate: environment?.dataDog?.sampleRate || 100,
            premiumSampleRate: environment?.dataDog?.premiumSampleRate || 100,
            trackInteractions: environment?.dataDog?.trackInteractions || false,
            allowedTracingOrigins: [] as ReadonlyArray<any>,
            beforeSend
        });
        datadogRum.onReady(() => resolve());
    });

    function beforeSend(event: RumEvent, context: RumEventDomainContext) {
        if (event.view.url.includes('?')) {
            event.view.url = event.view.url.split('?')[0];
        }
        if (event.type === 'resource' && event.resource.url.includes('?')) {
            event.resource.url = event.resource.url.split('?')[0];
        }
    }
}

export const DatadogInitializationProvider: FactoryProvider  = {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: factory,
    deps: [Environment],
    multi: true,
};
```

Does anyone of you have encountered the same issue?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day/evening!

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this issue locally. Can you share a little more about the configuration you are using that is causing this error and which version of the `@datadog/browser-rum` package you are using?

Comment: I'm seeing the same, did you fix this?

Comment: @DaveBower it is because I used the types from browser-rum-core... I will update the post with the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lievno, that explains my issue too

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the use of the types from browser-rum-core instead of browser-rum:

```
import { RumEvent } from '@datadog/browser-rum-core/src/rumEvent.types';
import { RumEventDomainContext } from '@datadog/browser-rum-core/src/domainContext.types';
import { datadogRum } from '@datadog/browser-rum';
```

instead of

```
import { datadogRum, RumEventDomainContext, RumEvent } from '@datadog/browser-rum';
```